# Pass a dummy struct or union to a function in C

Tags: c, struct, unions

This is one of those odd corner cases in C where C++ would likely handle it naturally, but where C doesn't seem to have a suitable idiom.

**Background**

I have a union (which could just as easily be a struct), something like this:

```
union foo {
    int a;
    char b;
    ...
};
```

The union is small:  Some of its types are "nontrivial", but it's guaranteed to fit within a processor register.

Because it's register-sized, I have functions that pass it around and return it directly, and that's safe and fast:

```
union foo bar(union foo x) {
    ...
}
```

Now, I have a whole batch of functions whose prototypes are generated by a macro, like this:

```
#define DECLARE_QUX(__y__) \
    static void qux(__y__ a, union foo b)
```

(All type names and `typedef`s have been changed to protect the innocent.)

This works fine, and in the target code it reads quite cleanly.  I can call the functions, pass around the unions, and everything looks and acts the way it should.

**The Problem**

But I bumped into an issue trying to call the generated `qux()` functions.  There are scenarios where I know that the union being passed to `qux()` is *completely irrelevant*.  It doesn't matter what's passed; I know the callee is going to ignore it.  But I can't change the `qux()` function's signature, so I'm forced to do this in order to be able to pass a useless "dummy" version of the union:

```
static union foo dummyUnion = { 0 };

qux(realData, dummyUnion);
```

That works, but it's sure clunky.  What I'd really love to be able to do is something like the "magic zero" of C++:

```
qux(realData, 0);
```

Or a C-ified version:

```
qux(realData, (foo)0);
```

But that doesn't work, of course, because you can't cast an integer to a union.

Reading through my copy of *K&R*, it doesn't look like this was ever really considered as part of the language; the ANSI standard added the ability to pass structs and unions directly (using `memcpy()` under the hood if necessary), mostly because every compiler already supported it.  But it doesn't look like they designed a way to declare such shapes with values in-situ, in the middle of an expression.

**The Question**

So, tl;dr:  Is there a way to declare a "dummy union" in-situ during a function call in C, or am I stuck with just declaring a `static` instance to pass in?

Comment: And Python handles it even smarter. You ae comparing apples and oranges. C and C++ are different languages. Btw: names starting with two underscores are reserved for the implementation at every scope. You must not use them in user-code. And K&R is outdates since decades (even K&R rev. 2 is oudated since 18 years); you should get a more recent book about modern C.

Comment: Passing a `struct` or `union` by value is often a bad idea. Why not pass a pointer? That way you can just pass a null pointer.

Comment: Because the overhead in dereferencing a pointer to a small struct may be higher than the overhead in simply passing it.  In this case, where I can be certain that the struct (union) fits within a register, the cost to dereference it to access the data inside would double the number of memory accesses for every usage of it.

Comment: As for K&R second edition, you're correct that it's old.  But it's also still the de-facto reference guide to C, written by C's creators, and is on more bookshelves than any other book on the subject.  It's not unreasonable to start there when asking the question "What does the language support?"

Comment: Well, you can put it on an altar, but it does not serve well as a reference to the language since 28 years (18 for rev 2). In addition C89(90 has some incompatibilities to the standard since C99. And with regard to "what the language supports", it is obviously a bad reference, as you should have noted by now. The only **authoritative** reference for the C language is IOS/IEC 9899:2011.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of further research finds that some compilers now allow this form:

```
qux(realData, (foo){ 0 });
```

Comparing *K&R* (second edition) to the [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), it looks like the *postfix-expression* production (see page 409, 6.5.2), has been extended to support a new form that didn't exist in the ANSI 1989 standard:

```
postfix-expression ::= ( type-name ) { initializer-list }
```

This solves the exact problem, and works for both structs and unions.

That said, I'm not sure which compilers are compliant with that new production (VC++ 2013 seems to accept it, and I'll bet GCC and clang would too).  But since it's now defined by the C standard, it looks good enough to use in real code.

Comment: That's not what "some compilers allow", but standard. As I wrote above: get a more recent C book. Btw: C99 is not standard. Is has been canceled with the release of C11.

Comment: I think it's accurate to say it's what "some compilers allow."  ANSI C '89 compilers would prohibit that form.  Given that no C compilers accept an identical version of the language, knowing which compiler you're on matters.

Comment: C89, aka ANSI-C is not standard C since a very long time. And the C tag here refers to standard C, read the info page. "Given that no C compilers accept an identical version of the language" - sorry, but that's nonsense. What a C11 compiler has to support is clearly defined by the standard. Compound literals are one of the mandatory features (since C99). It is not a matter of "some compilers, but about compliant compilers. It is a very bad idea to use a compiler not supporting **at least** modern C(99). And in fact on a PC and most modern embedded targets there is actually no reason.

Comment: Microsoft claims to sell a C compiler.  It supports a variety of constructs that the C standard doesn't include (`__declspec`, declarations anywhere in a function, etc.).  GNU claims to offer a C compiler.  It supports a variety of constructs that C standard doesn't include (statement expressions, local labels, etc.).  Lots of compilers supported `//` comments before C99.  Everybody's C compiler is different, and none of them exactly match the standard (_any_ of the standards).  So I'm going to reiterate my claim that knowing which compiler you're on matters.

Comment: MS never claimed thir compiler is **compliant** to the standard. The C tag refers to **standard C** which is the only reasonable common denominator for the language. gcc is clear about supporting standard C, so does clang. Both compiler allow to select which version of the standard they support, with gcc defaulting to the standard, i.e. C11. Your approach testing for the compiler is thus nonsense. You have to test for the standard if at all. Simplest solution is to require a compliant compiler, which I made clear is no problem at all to find. And there is only **one** C standard. Just read it.